# The active textures don't get recognized as keyframes

Tags: animation, texturing, fcurves

I'm trying to animate a character's eyes using the F-Curve, I basically want to switch between textures in the animation. The problem is: whether I right click -> Insert Keyframe, or I use "i", or manually edit the curve, the changes I do to the active textures don't get stored in keyframes, if I toggle an active texture and press "i" it doesn't change anything. When I go back to a keyframe where I should have inserted a modify the state of the active textures stay the same. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Did you press "i" on the checkbox, or the panel?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Gilderman, you have keyframed the Active Texture Index, hence the texture box being yellow, rather than the Use Textures checkbox.  Only add single keyframe otherwise you will end up with an fcurve for all texture slots, used or not.

[image]

The index on the fcurve, which is shown on fcurve editor,  "`[1] Use Textures`" indicates which slot, starting from zero, the texture is in.

The "Active Texture Index" is more of a UI thing as it indicates which texture details to display on the panel, by setting the active_texture_index of the material.

My suggestion would be to add a custom property for eyes open / closed and then drive the use_texture with this.

Comment: Oh, thanks man! Now it's all clearer! How do I create a custom property anyway?